# jQuery plugin in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am trying to use this plugin for autosizing a textarea in Meteor: https://atmospherejs.com/copleykj/jquery-autosize

This is what I try to do

```
Template.writer.rendered({
  $textarea = ('#textarea-selector', $(this.firstNode)); // Second argument establishes jQuery context
  $textarea.autosize();
});
```

And then I have a textarea in a template called writer. But it does not work, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What does this refer to?

Comment: @Sindis: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I'm trying to implement a plugin that can resize textareas automatically when you put in more lines than there is space. I have tried following the instructions from the plugins page, as shown above, but I think I make some mistake somewhere..

Comment: @Sindis: Maybe this is what you mean, it should refer to the following textarea (which is inside a template called writer): <textarea id="writingspace" wrap="on"></textarea>

Comment: Does $('#textarea-selector').autosize(); work? Because it's weird initialization with `this` keyword

Comment: The `#textarea-selector` refers to the id of the text area. So you need to do `<textarea id="#textarea-selector" wrap="on"></textarea>` or change the javascript to reference "writingspace".

Comment: Autumn Leonard: thanks! This together with Ryan Wu's answer made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Meteor you're using?

In the latest version (1.2.0.2) you have to use the `onRendered` callback instead of `rendered`

```
Template.writer.onRendered(function() {
  $textarea = ('#textarea-selector', $(this.firstNode)); // Second argument establishes jQuery context
  $textarea.autosize();
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is strictly true. While `rendered` is deprecated, it still works.